# Use heatmap.js in cesium.js

Tags: javascript, heatmap, cesiumjs

I'm interested in showing a heatmap in my Cesium application. On the [heatmap.js website](http://www.patrick-wied.at/static/heatmapjs/) they have a number of demos such as the [leaflet demo](http://www.patrick-wied.at/static/heatmapjs/example-heatmap-leaflet.html) which adds the heatmap object as a layer. I'm wondering if there is a way to do such a thing in Cesium.js. I've seen people mention rendering a (or multiple) PNG(s) and showing that as a layer, that's a viable option if there is a way that I can do it on the fly and add them to my Cesium instance.

I have seen [examples of heatmaps in Cesium](https://youtu.be/81l6gdSo-10?t=7m) but it's never explained how they did that (I don't even know if they used heatmap.js). There is also an issue on the [Cesium.js GitHub](https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/cesium/issues/2208) about this, but they don't seem to be actively pursuing it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because there was nothing to my liking I created 2 libraries to incorporate [heatmap.js](http://www.patrick-wied.at/static/heatmapjs/) into Cesium. Both can be found on [my GitHub](https://github.com/dragon112/CesiumHeatmap). They are called:

**CesiumHeatmap**

This is a library that uses either a `Entity.Rectangle` or the `SingleTileImageryProvider` to show the heatmap on the globe.

**HeatmapImageryProvider**

This is a library that uses a custom `Cesium.ImageryProvider` to show the heatmap on the globe.

Comment: Hey! I appreciate the work you put into this library and I'm trying to incorporate it into my Cesium app. I've got the CesiumHeatmap working and am working on incorporating the HeatmapImageryProvider now. Looks like you haven't posted lately here or in Github but have you kept up with or played with the library lately?

Comment: No I haven't worked on it in a long while, I'll probably take a look at it in the (near) future. Feel free to play around with it yourself.

Comment: Gotcha, just curious since it seems really useful. I'll be playing around with it. Thanks for checking in.

Comment: Hey quick question if it's convenient to answer, it looks from a post here: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/cesium-dev/Qhos2CpA1cY/dkHxCi4KDjAJ like at some point you were able to show the heatmap in Cesium with a transparent background, showing the map below. Any quick tips on how that was achieved? I'm still only able to show a heatmap with an entirely black background.

Comment: What version of Cesium are you using?

Comment: I'm using Cesium 1.28 currently.

Comment: Hmm well I haven't yet gotten the HeatMapImageryProvider working yet, if that happened to be what you were using. I'll keep trying at it. Thanks for getting back to me.